# How to display a unicoded character like Euro symbols in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have visualforce where in the output label i need to display an Euro symbol. I tried with couple of  unicoded character in the output label, but it doesn't rendered. Below i have given the screenshot for the reference.

```
<apex:outputLabel value="Price for custom decalaration (in \u20AC)"/>

<apex:outputLabel value="Costs (in &#x20ac;)"/>
```

Kindly help me. What is the way that i need to display an euro symbol in a visualforce page?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of choices:

1. The easiest is to just copy and paste it in. The system should generate the correct symbol for you.
2. Add `escape="false"` to the `apex:outputLabel`. This will cause the value to be rendered literally, thus emitting the correct HTML code as you expect. Use the € notation, as \u20AC would only be used in other contexts, not in Visualforce attributes.

Comment: :@sfdcfox : Thanks a lot, as simple i used the first option